# Showing that $\frac{2L/c}{1-\beta^2}-\frac{2L/c}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}=\frac{L\beta^2}{c}+O(\beta^4)$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

I'm stuck at an exercise in a relativity text. We need to prove that

$$\frac{2L/c}{1-\beta^2}-\frac{2L/c}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}=\frac{L\beta^2}{c}+O(\beta^4)$$

for small $\beta$.

I have tried out the Maclaurin expansion of both expressions on the LHS, but I'm not getting the RHS result from that. The expansion of the second term in LHS in particular is quite complicated and I think there must be a simpler way to prove. Would like some help on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track by thinking to use a series expansion. A simple binomial expansion actually suffices,

$\frac{2L}{c} (1-\beta^{2})^{-1} - \frac{2L}{c}(1-\beta^{2})^{-\frac{1}{2}} = (\frac{2L}{c} + \frac{2L\beta^{2}}{c} + O[\beta^{4}]) - (\frac{2L}{c} + \frac{L\beta^{2}}{c} + O[\beta^{4}])$

And this, once you cancel the $\frac{2L}{c}$'s and combine the remaining fractions reduces to

$\frac{L\beta^{2}}{c} + O[\beta^{4}]$, as required.